# How did I get "Windows Input Experience" folder in my Downloads folder?

Tags: windows, on-screen-keyboard, files-folders

I see a random folder on my downloads folder called `Downloads/Windows Input Experience`

I did not create this. I quickly did a search. I think it is something to do with the On screen keyboard which I was trying before and I see that it was created about 30mins ago which seems about right

But can somebody tell me what application created this folder
[image]

Comment: I think that windows does not log information like that .... download process monitor from Microsoft... use it to discover which program accesses that folder ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Process explorer is the one you mean i am sure.

Comment: no, not process explorer ... you can configure process monitor to start at boot time ... then you can examine the trace log for accesses to the folder from the begining of windows startup

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Explorer if you want to see which process is using a folder.

But in this case, The `Downloads/Windows Input Experience` is used by the windows emoji keyboard. You can press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>(period) and it brings up the emoji window which you can also insert gif. The gifs are saved in `Downloads/Windows Input Experience`